# Event tagging for Slider

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

Tags are firing multiple times when slider arrow click reaches last image.

1. I am using google tag manager.
2. Here the slider is in a for loop .When the slider reaches the last
   image.It is iterating the click function multiple times.

> **Below is the code I have added as a tag using Custom HTML script .**

```
    $('MySliderArrowClass').click(function(){ 

 //Fire An event one time 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your slider has more images in the code to make the slider transition more seemless.